# Explain the solution to: what is the probability that no letter is in its proper envelope?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

Five letters are addressed to five different people and the corresponding envelopes are prepared. The letters are put into the envelopes at random. What is the probability that no letter is in its proper envelope?

Here is my thought process:

- I know that this probability is the same as $1$ - (probability that at least one is in the correct envelope)
- Let $A$ be the event that at least on is in the correct envelope
- $A = P(\text{exactly } 1) + P(\text{exactly } 2) + ... + P(\text{all } 5)$
- $P(\text{exactly } 1) = \dfrac{5 \choose 1}{5!}$, $P(\text{exactly } 2) = \dfrac{5 \choose 2}{5!}$, ...

However, this is not the correct solution. It seems I should be using the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, but this doesn't make sense to me. What is wrong with my thought process above? Can someone help explain?

Thank y'all!

Comment: How do you get $P(\text{exactly 1}) = \frac{\binom51}{5!}$? There are more than $\binom51$ permutations that have exactly one fixed point.

Comment: Note that $P(\text{exactly 4}) =0$ since if you have four out of five correct, the remaining one must also be correct as there is nowhere else for it to go

Comment: I see my error in counting the permutations here. How would you go about finding the number of combinations of exactly 1 letter in the right envelope? Would it then be $1*3^4$? My thought process here is that there is only 1 way for the first envelope to be correct. Then for the other 4 envelopes, there are only 3 options for each envelope because we do not want the correct letter for the envelope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One mistake that stands out is that you seem to be confusing the statements "at least $x$ is in the correct envelope" with "exactly $x$ in the correct envelope." Furthermore, there aren't only $5$ permutations with exactly one fixed point (from the problem you've shared).

In any case, you typically want to use the [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) for problems like these. If you had $n$ letters, then the number of derangements is
$$D_n = n! \left(\frac{1}{2!} - \frac{1}{3!} + \frac{1}{4!} + \ldots + \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\right),$$
and so the probability you want is $D_n/n!$.

Comment: Derangement does make this very easy, thank you! I would still like to understand how to count the number of ways to get exactly $x$ correct envelopes. From the comments above, I see my error in my original post.

My next thought for exactly 1 envelope correct is $1*3^4$ where $1$ is the number of ways for envelope 1 to be correct and $3^4$ is the number of ways for the other envelopes to be wrong. Is this correct?